# Theorem 29.1 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY: A Problem in the Proof of the Uniqueness Part

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, compactness

Here is Theorem 29.1 in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $X$ be a [topological] space. Then $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff if and only if there exists a [topological] space $Y$ satisfying the following conditions:

> (1) $X$ is a subspace of $Y$.

> (2) The set $Y - X$ consists of a single point.

> (3) $Y$ is a compact Hausdorff space.

> If $Y$ and $Y^\prime$ are two spaces satisfying these conditions, then there exists a homeomorphism of $Y$ with $Y^\prime$ that equals the identity map on $X$.

Here is the initial part of Munkres' proof:

Step 1

> We first verify uniqueness. Let $Y$ and $Y^\prime$ be two [topological] spaces satisfying these conditions. Define $h : Y \longrightarrow Y^\prime$ by letting $h$ map the single point $p$ of $Y - X$ to the point $q$ of $Y^\prime - X$, and letting $h$ equal the identity on $X$. We show that if $U$ is open in $Y$, then $h(U)$ is open in $Y^\prime$. Symmetry then implies that $h$ is a homeomorphism.

> First, consider the case where  $U$ does not contain $p$. Then $h(U) = U$. Since $U$ is open in $Y$ and is contained in $X$, it is open in $X$. Because $X$ is open in $Y^\prime$, the set $U$ is also open in $Y^\prime$, as desired.

Now my question is as follows:

> Since $U$ is open in $Y$ and contained in $X$, it is open in $X$ --- when $X$ is regarded as a subspace of $Y$ and not necessarily when $X$ is regarded as a subspace of $Y^\prime$. Because $X$ is open in $Y^\prime$, how does it follow from this that $U$, which is open in the subspace $X$ of $Y$ and not necessarily open in the subspace $X$ of $Y^\prime$, is also open in $Y^\prime$? After all, until the final conclusion of the theorem has actually been established,  $Y$ and $Y^\prime$ are different (i.e. potentially non-homeomorphic) topological spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subspace topologies that $X$ inherits from $Y$ and from $Y'$ are identical, so it's rather trivial that if $U\subseteq X$ is an open subset in one of the topologies, it's open in the other.

As for why this implies openness in $Y'$: In general, given that $X\subseteq Y'$ is open and $U\subseteq X$, the following two are equivalent:

- $U$ is open in $X$
- $U$ is open in $Y'$

The upward implication is a straight-forward application of the definition of subspace topology, and doesn't use the openness of $X$.

The downward implication may be proven as follows: By the definition of subspace topology, there is an open subset $U'\subseteq Y$ such that $X\cap U'=U$. But the left-hand side is an intersection of two open subsets of $Y'$. So it's open in $Y'$.

Comment: thank you for answering my question, but what you have written in your answer is clear to me already. My issue is that $U$ is open in $X$ but _when $X$ is regarded as a subspace of $Y$_. _This certainly does not imply that this $U$ would also be open in $X$ when $X$ is regarded as a subspace of $Y^\prime$_. How then do we conclude that $U$ is also open in $Y^\prime$ as well? Hope the gist of my question is clear now.

Comment: how do we know for sure that the subspace topologies inherited by $U$ as a subspace of $Y$ and of $Y^\prime$ are indeed identical? After all, this is what is to be proved in the uniqueness part.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood Property (1): $X$ is a subspace of $Y$ and $X$ is a subspace of $Y'$. That includes the already established and fixed topology on $X$ (otherwise Munkres would've said "subset", I trust him that much).

Comment: from your comment I gather the following: Subset $X$ of both $Y$ and $Y^\prime$ with a given _fixed_ topology is a subspace of both $Y$ and $Y^\prime$. The subspace topologies on $X$ as a subspace of $Y$ and of $Y^\prime$ are given to be both equal to that _fixed_ topology on $X$ that is assumed in the hypothesis of the theorem. Am I right?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood We start with a topological space $X$, with some topology $\tau$. Then we are given two topological spaces $Y$ and $Y'$, and they both satisfy some list of properties. One of those properties is that $X$ is a subset and the induced subspace topology on $X$ is $\tau$. So throughout all of this theorem and its proof, there is only ever a single topology on $X$.