# Theorem 29.1 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY: Another Problem in the Uniqueness Part

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, compactness

Here is Theorem 29.1 in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $X$ be a [topological] space. Then $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff if and only if there exists a [topological] space $Y$ satisfying the following conditions:

> (1) $X$ is a subspace of $Y$.

> (2) The set $Y - X$ consists of a single point.

> (3) $Y$ is a compact Hausdorff space.

> If $Y$ and $Y^\prime$ are two spaces satisfying these conditions, then there exists a homeomorphism of $Y$ with $Y^\prime$ that equals the identity map on $X$.

Here is the initial part of Munkres' proof:

Step 1

> We first verify uniqueness. Let $Y$ and $Y^\prime$ be two [topological] spaces satisfying these conditions. Define $h : Y \longrightarrow Y^\prime$ by letting $h$ map the single point $p$ of $Y - X$ to the point $q$ of $Y^\prime - X$, and letting $h$ equal the identity on $X$. We show that if $U$ is open in $Y$, then $h(U)$ is open in $Y^\prime$. Symmetry then implies that $h$ is a homeomorphism.

> First, consider the case where  $U$ does not contain $p$. Then $h(U) = U$. Since $U$ is open in $Y$ and is contained in $X$, it is open in $X$. Because $X$ is open in $Y^\prime$, the set $U$ is also open in $Y^\prime$, as desired.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4220852/theorem-29-1-in-munkres-topology-a-problem-in-the-proof-of-the-uniqueness-part) is my Math Stack Exchange question on the argument given in the preceding paragraph.

> Second, suppose that $U$ contains $p$. Since $C = Y - U$ is closed in $Y$, it is compact as a subspace of $Y$. Because $C$ is contained in $X$, it is a compact subspace of $X$. Then because $X$ is a subspace of $Y^\prime$, the space $C$ is also a compact subspace of $Y^\prime$. ...

Now my question is as follows:

> Although $C$ is compact as a subspace of the topological space $X$ *when $X$ has the subspace topology that $X$ inherits from $Y$*, how do we gaurantee from this that $C$ would also be compact as a subspace of $X$ *but when $X$ has the subspace topology that $X$ inherits from $Y^\prime$*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X$ has a fixed topology. If you take any bigger space $Z \supset X$ such that $X$ is a **subspace** of $Z$, then by definiton the subspace topology on $X$ inherited from $Z$ is the original topology on $X$. The situation would be different if we only require that the underlying set of $X$ is a subset of $Z$. In that case the subspace topology on $X$ inherited from $Z$ can be anything; there is no relation to the original topology on $X$.